# Track if the email is marked as spam

Tags: asp.net, spam, email-spam

I have an asp.net autoresponder that sends emails to millions of subscribers. I want to track if a person mark my emails as spam. is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://www.mxtoolbox.com/ as an example of sites to use for checking if your server/sending IP is blacklisted.

You can also sign up for feedback loop services with major or relevant email providers for your list(s) to be informed when messages are reported as spam. Feedback loops are probably the best mechanism for the information you are trying to gather.

Example of a feedback loop and how to subscribe to it:
http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.FeedbackLoop.php

I can't post more than 2 links but if you Google "feedback loop" and the name of the email provider you are likely to find what you need to sign up for their alerts.

Hope that helps.